# How to execute jar in Mac OS X using SWT/Eclipse?

Tags: java, swt, executable, executable-jar

I changed the Java to 32 bit mode, to allow the SWT run, when I debug, it works well. But when I use Eclipse to export .jar, it shows this error.

[image: Error dialog]

I already added chmod 777.  What did I do wrong?

Here is the console result:

```
20/11/2011 12:10:36 AM  [0x0-0x3d89d86].com.apple.JarLauncher[73111]    Exception in thread "main" 
20/11/2011 12:10:36 AM  [0x0-0x3d89d86].com.apple.JarLauncher[73111]    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load 32-bit SWT libraries on 64-bit JVM
20/11/2011 12:10:36 AM  [0x0-0x3d89d86].com.apple.JarLauncher[73111]        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
20/11/2011 12:10:36 AM  [0x0-0x3d89d86].com.apple.JarLauncher[73111]        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
20/11/2011 12:10:36 AM  [0x0-0x3d89d86].com.apple.JarLauncher[73111]        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
20/11/2011 12:10:36 AM  [0x0-0x3d89d86].com.apple.JarLauncher[73111]        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
20/11/2011 12:10:36 AM  [0x0-0x3d89d86].com.apple.JarLauncher[73111]        at com.testing.SWTApp.main(SWTApp.java:54)
```

The MANIFEST is like follow:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: com.testing.SWTApp
```

Comment: What's the error message in the console?

Comment: How can I see the manifest file? I didn't do anything on it.

Comment: updated question with console result.

Comment: To get the MANIFEST.MF file you'll want to pull it from the jar file. e.g. `unzip app.jar META-INF/*`. You'll want to look at that file in your favorite text editor to see that it has a Main-Class attribute. executing from the command line should be something akin to `java -jar app.jar`

Comment: Actually on a mac, you could also launch from the command line using `open app.jar` and the "console" to which your dialog and @Perception were referring is /Applications/Utilities/Console.app not Terminal.app

Comment: thx ach_l, I think I got the answer, but I already set the eclipse in 32 bits mode via...preference > Java > Installed JREs > Default VM Argument : "-d32"

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
java -d32 -XstartOnFirstThread -jar myapp.jar
```

The `-d32` option will cause the VM to run in 32-bit mode. The `-XstartOnFirstThread` option is necessary for SWT applications.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is it's not Eclipse that is executing your built jar, it's Finder / the java launcher. What you need to do is goto `/Applications/Utilities/Java Preferences.app` and reorder (click drag) so that your 32 bit version is chosen before the 64 bit version. For reference mine looks like this:

[image: My Java Preferences]

then when you execute `java -version` (no `-d` parameter) you'll get the 32 bit JRE chosen. and when you double click the jar in finder or use `open app.jar` it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
20/11/2011 12:10:36 AM  [0x0-0x3d89d86].com.apple.JarLauncher[73111]    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load 32-bit SWT libraries on 64-bit JVM
```

Please focus on this error. You need 64-bit dependency libraries for launching it. It depends on default java loaded. If its 32-bit package, you need your default jvm classpath to be 32-bit java. You have option for changing it in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

the swt jar executes native librairies which depend on your OS.
You have one version of swt for:
macosx 32 & 64 bits
winsows 32 & 64 bits
linux 32 & 64 bits

you can specify the `-d32` jvm option. It will force the JVM to run in the 32 bits mode. However, you need to have a 32 bits implementation of the JVM available in your OS.

You could also load dynamically at runtime the right SWT Jar: you include in your app both jar (swt-macosx-32bits & swt-macosx-64bits) and load programatically the required jar:

```
String osArch = System.getProperty ("sun.arch.data.model");
if (osArch == null) {
    osArch = System.getProperty ("com.ibm.vm.bitmode");
}
URLClassLoader classLoader = (URLClassLoader) JarLoaderUtils.class.getClassLoader();
URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(new RsrcURLStreamHandlerFactory(classLoader));
Method addUrlMethod = URLClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", URL.class);
addUrlMethod.setAccessible(true);
swtFileName = osArch.contains("64") ? SWT_MAC_x86_64 : SWT_MAC_x86;
URL swtFileUrl = new URL("rsrc:" + swtFileName);
addUrlMethod.invoke(classLoader, swtFileUrl);
```

Note that you seem to run your app in macosx, you should also add the `-XstartOnFirstThread` option.